# width/height ratio preserved after a call to qtextimageformat.setWidth()?

Tags: qt5, image-resizing, qimage, qtextdocument

In order to insert an image in a *QTextDocument* I have to modify its width and its height and to keep the original image's ratio. Hence my code :

```
qtextimageformat.setWidth( new_width );
cursor.insertImage( qtextimageformat, position )
```

I thought it was mandatory to modify **the width and height** but I was surprized to see that the call to .setWidth() somehow preserved the image's ratio, as if .setHeight() was implicitly called with the right parameter.

Is this the expected behaviour ? Or I am missing something ? [The documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextimageformat.html#setWidth) didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior, even if it is not explicit in documentation. The static functions `QSize getImageSize(QTextDocument *doc, const QTextImageFormat &format)` and `QSize getPixmapSize(QTextDocument *doc, const QTextImageFormat &format)` in `qtextimagehandler.cpp` automatically deduce the height if only width was specified in `QTextImageFormat` (and the opposite too)